# Comparing two state variables in React

Tags: reactjs

I'd like to compare two pieces of state in a React component, which are both set on the click of a button. My problem is that when the second button is clicked, the compare function is called straight away before the state is updated, so I continually get a 'no match'. Here's a breakdown of the code (this is a single button component - which is displayed several times through a forEach loop. There are two pieces of state - first and second - which are integers).

```
const handleSelection = (e) => {
    if (!first) {
        setFirst(e.target.dataset.id);
    } else if (!second) {
        setSecond(e.target.dataset.id);
        checkMatch();
    } else {
        setFirst(e.target.dataset.id);
        setSecond(undefined);
    }
}   

const checkMatch = () => {
    if(first === second) {
        console.log('match');
    } else {
        console.log('no match');
    }
}


return (
    <div className="grid-item">
        <button onClick={(e) => handleSelection(e)} data-id={item.number}>{item.number}</button>
    </div>
)
```

Comment: You should probably `checkMatch` in `useEffect` with `[first, second]` dependancies

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [useEffect hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) can help you subscribe to any changes in your state as soon as one of the values passed as dependencies is updated.

So instead of having your `checkMatch` function, you could do:

```
useEffect(() => {
   if (first === second) {
      console.log('match');
   } else {
      console.log('no match');
   }
}, [first, second]);
```

In this example, `first` and `second` are the dependencies of your `useEffect` hook and will call the callback function (the first parameter of `useEffect`) any time one of these state variables has been updated.